# Prove that $\sec^2{\theta}=(4xy)/(x+y)^2$ only when $x=y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Show that the equation below is only possible when $x=y$
>   $$ \sec^2{\theta}=\frac{4xy}{(x+y)^2}$$

---

The only way I can think of doing this is by rewriting it as

$$ \cos^2{\theta}=\frac{(x+y)^2}{4xy} $$
then using some inequalities to prove it by using:
$$ 0\leq \cos^2{\theta}\leq 1 \;\; \text{ therefore } \;\; 0\leq \frac{(x+y)^2}{4xy}\leq 1 $$
But I have an aversion to using case-based solutions (checking for $x>0$, $y>0$ etc.) since I feel there must be a neater solution to  these kind of problems. So my question is: Is it possible to solve this and these sort of questions using techniques that don't involve checking numerous cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have $\sec^2 \theta\ge 1$ for all $\theta$ at which $\sec\theta$ is defined.  So it is enough to show that $\frac{4xy}{(x+y)^2}\le 1$, with equality only when $x=y$.

To show that $\frac{4xy}{(x+y)^2}\le 1$, we show equivalently that $(x+y)^2\ge 4xy$, or equivalently that $x^2-2xy+y^2\ge 0$. But this is clear, since $x^2-2xy+y^2=(x-y)^2$. And we have equality precisely when $x=y$.

**Remark:** This is not very different from how you proposed to do things. There are no cases involved. And aversion to cases can be problematic. A consideration of cases (though not in this case) is often a natural approach.

Comment: This is a much neater inequality, I'm not sure why I didn't just stick with $\sec^2{\theta}$ as it would have saved me from doing the dreaded cases. I don't like doing it with cases just because it *feels* (to me anyway) like there must exist a more condensed statement that would convey the same thing just in a more succinct way (like in this case), though of course such a form may not always exist but I aspire to try and find them! Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. My feeling is that first one should produce a correct proof. Through the process of producing that proof, one may discover a more succinct argument. Historically, even for (in retrospect) fairly elementary theorems, condensed conceptual proofs have sometimes followed first proofs only after many years.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sec^2\theta=\frac{4xy}{(x+y)^2}\implies\tan^2\theta=\frac{4xy}{(x+y)^2}-1=-\frac{(x+y)^2-4xy}{(x+y)^2}=-\left(\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right)^2$$

$$\iff\tan^2\theta+\left(\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right)^2=0\ \ \ \ (1)$$

For real $\displaystyle \theta,\tan^2\theta\ge0$

and for real $\displaystyle  x,y;  \left(\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right)^2\ge0$

So, each has to be individually zero to satisfy $(1)$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$$
\mbox{Let's}\quad r \equiv {x \over x + y}\quad\mbox{such that}\quad
{4xy \over \pars{x + y}^{2}} = 4r\pars{1 - r} =1 - \pars{2r - 1}^{2} \leq 1
$$

> Since $\ds{\sec^{2}\pars{\theta} \geq 1}$ the only solution occurs when $\ds{r = \half}$ which leads to $\color{#00f}{\large x = y}$.

Answer (score 1):

$4xy$ can be rearranged as $(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2$, and therefore $\sec^2\theta=\frac{(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2}{(x+y)^2}=1-\left ( \frac{x-y}{x+y} \right )^2$, which is always less than or equal to $1$ because $\left ( \frac{x-y}{x+y} \right )^2$ is greater than or equal to $0$.

Recall that $-1\le \cos\theta\le1\Rightarrow \cos^2\theta\le1\Rightarrow \sec^2\theta\ge1$.

We have therefore established that $\sec^2\theta\le1$ and also that $\sec^2\theta\ge1$; both of these conditions can be satisfied only if $\sec^2\theta=1$.

$\Rightarrow 1-\left ( \frac{x-y}{x+y} \right )^2=1\Rightarrow \left ( \frac{x-y}{x+y} \right )^2=0$

Now if $x$ and $y$ are not equal to $0$, then the denominator $x+y\ne 0 \Rightarrow x=y$ and neither of which is equal to $0 \blacksquare$

Answer (score -1):

from jay 
we can show that

$$(x+y)^2 \le 4xy$$

$$x^2+y^2+2xy \le 4xy$$

$$x^2+y^2-2xy \le 0$$

$$(x-y)^2 \le 0$$

$$x-y \le 0$$

$$x=y$$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please take a look at [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information about formatting your answer to make it easier to read.